# Create select query how to convert varchar to int by using cast

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, casting, substring

I want to convert the values

```
2to5experience

3to7experience
```

to
Minexperience:

```
2
3
```

Maxexperience

```
5
7
```

So i create the following query,

```
select cast(substring(Cast(Experience AS VARCHAR(50)),1,1)*365*24*60*60 as int) as Experience 
      from requirementsdetailsfororganization
```

The above one is working. when i update the query like following, I am getting an error.

```
select 'Insert into Jobs(requirementId,organizationId,Minexperience)values(' + 
   Cast(o.RequirementID as varchar(50))+',' +
   Cast(o.OrganizationID as varchar(50))+',' +
   cast(substring(CAST(Experience AS VARCHAR(50)),1,1)*365*24*60*60 as int)+')'
   FROM RequirementsDetailsforOrganization AS o
```

It shows error

"**Conversion failed when converting the varchar value** ')' to data type int"

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second to last row in your select you cast the expression to `int` and then add (using `+`) a `)`. Since the value on the left of the `+` is an integer, SQL Server tries to convert the operand to the right of the `+` to an integer too.

Try changing the cast to `int` so that you instead cast it to `varchar`:

```
select 'Insert into Jobs(requirementId,organizationId,Minexperience)values(' + 
   Cast(o.RequirementID as varchar(50))+',' +
   Cast(o.OrganizationID as varchar(50))+',' +
   cast(substring(CAST(Experience AS VARCHAR(50)),1,1)*365*24*60*60 as varchar(50))+')'
   FROM RequirementsDetailsforOrganization AS o
```

Note:

The cast of `Experience` to `varchar` is probably superfluous.

Comment: i have a problem. when i try to select 2to17years means it takes with 2 17y like that. how can rectify that?

Comment: @AngDei See Marimuthu's answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try with following Steps.

```
--Create Table :
Create Table #Table
(
Name Varchar(50),
Experience Varchar(20)
)
Go

-- Insert Values :
Insert into #Table Values('Tom','0to0experience')
Insert into #Table Values('Victor','0to1experience')
Insert into #Table Values('Mark','11to12experience')
Go

--View Data
Select  * from #Table

--Using CharIndex  and Substring :
Select Name,
Substring(Experience,1,CharIndex('to',Experience)-1) as Yearfrom,
Substring(Experience,(CharIndex('to',Experience)+2),Len(Replace(Experience,'experience','')) - (CharIndex('to',Experience)+1)) as YearTo
from #Table

--Clean Up:
Drop Table #Table
```